# Web Service SMS SOAP

Tags: php, sms

Tenho meu proprio codigo de envio de SMS em Web Service SOAP PHP como voces veem abaixo:

```
       <?php

    try {
    $webservice = new SoapClient("https://services.tvest.net.br:62003/sys/wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "login" => "blabla", "password" =>                                                               
     "blablabla"));
   } catch (Exception $e) {
   print_r($e);
  exit;
  }


   $webservice->enviarSMS("5522998318901", "teste");

     ?>
```

A Pergunta é:   como Vou iniciar um PHP de Login de confirmação por SMS a partir desse codigo, estou com dificuldades !!!

Comment: o que você quer dizer com: " iniciar um PHP de Login de confirmação por SMS" ?

Comment: quero comecar a criar um autenticador por sms,   cliente coloca o numero do celular e vai um codigo para ele e ele se autentica na minha base

Comment: O que esse cliente vai precisar colocar para o sistema enviar o SMS? Só o numero de celular? Esse número já esta gravado em algum lugar?

Comment: so o numero do celular !!! e mais nada